# z-index ignored: 2 fixed divs, 1 of them in a position relative div

Tags: css

I had a hard title coming up with a title. I'm having trouble with the twitter bootstrap overlay appearing on top of a modal window, I'm able to illustrate my problem with the below html. I've also provided a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UnTvQ/2/).

```
<div style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">
    <div style="background: blue; position: fixed; z-index: 3;">
    </div>
</div>
<div style="background: green; position: fixed; z-index: 2; top: 0">
</div>​
```

How can I get the blue div to appear on top of the green div? Why is the green div on top of the blue div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi now used to this demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/UnTvQ/5/

Define top div `z-index`

```
<div style="position: relative; z-index: 3;">
    <div style="background: blue; position: fixed;">
    </div>
</div>
<div style="background: green; position: fixed; z-index: 2; top: 20px; left:10px;">
</div>
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/UnTvQ/5/)**

Learn more about  **How to work** `z-index` link ***[here](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/40-how-z-index-works/)***